# How to put LWC inside a Salesforce tab?

Tags: lightning-web-components, page-layout

I'm new as a Salesforce developer. I'm trying to create an LWC to place inside a tab, but the component is being placed outside the allowable area. As shown in the image below.
[image]

This is my HTML code that I build :

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Teste">
<table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-no-row-hover slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered" aria-label="Example table of Opportunities with vertical borders">
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
            <th class="" scope="col" colspan="9">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Opportunity Name">Id</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
            <th data-label="Opportunity Name" scope="row">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">{Name}</div>
            </th>
            <th data-label="Account Name">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="DocNum">CPF</div>
            </th>
            <th data-label="Close Date">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Date">birth date</div>
            </th>
            <th data-label="Prospecting">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="MotherName">mother's name</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
            <th data-label="Opportunity Name" scope="row">
               <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Teste Admin</div>
            </th>
            <th data-label="Account Name">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="DocNum">343.928.798-01</div>
            </th>
            <th data-label="Close Date">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Date">04/05/1992</div>
            </th>
            <th data-label="Prospecting">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="MotherName">Mother Admin</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="slds-hint-parent" >
            <th data-label="Opportunity Name" scope="row" colspan="9">
               <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Status Doc</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
            <th data-label="Opportunity Name" scope="row" colspan="9">
               <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Status CPF in 26/06/2021 : regular</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</lightning-card>
```

Why is this happening? And how can I solve this problem?

Comment: This does look correct, but UI is not rendered as per html. Do you have any custom css file being uploaded which overrides standard slds css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied all your code and it shows as expected for me.

[image]

Here the code :

[image]

So maybe there is any custom css file being uploaded which overrides standard slds css?

Otherwise I suggest using standard **Lightning datatable** : [Lightning datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) .

Which can help you in developing and will save your time.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are really correct.
I went to investigate and there was a css file customizing the table with a float: left.

It's perfect now!